# Почему затирается предыдущий обект вектора при повторном вызове `emplace_back`?

Tags: c++, vector, деструктор

По внешнем цикле идёт захват кадров, которые передаются в кодировщик...
При `Push` второго кадра почему-то вызывается деструктор первого. Специально закомментировал все места, где удаляются элементы вектора, всё равно объект разрушается. В чём тут может быть проблема?

```
bool cv_streamer::Push(unsigned char *data){
    if(!error){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_framestack);
        if( timer > 0){
            unsigned int duration = clock() - timer;
            framestack.back().duration = duration;
            timer+= duration;
        }
        else{timer = clock();}
        printf("Adding a frame...\n");

        // при повторном вызове первый объект затирается
        framestack.emplace_back(data, cfg.g_w, cfg.g_h); 

        if(!framestack.back().ready){ // никогда не срабатывало, всё ОК
            framestack.pop_back();
            printf("Error occured. Frame deleted\n");
            timer = 0;
            error = 1;
        }
        else printf("PTS: %u\n",framestack.front().duration);
    }
    printf("Frame added\n");
    return !error;
}

struct frame{
    bool ready;
    unsigned int duration;
    vpx_image_t image;
    frame(unsigned char *data, unsigned int w, unsigned int h){
        duration = 0;
        ready = (vpx_img_alloc(&image, VPX_IMG_FMT_I420, w, h, 1) != NULL);
        if( ready){colorspaces::BGRtoI420(w, h, data, image.planes[0], image.planes[1], image.planes[2]);}
    }
    ~frame(){
        vpx_img_free(&image);
        printf("Frame destructor called\n");
    }
};
```

[image: log]

Comment: В Вашем примере кода есть все, кроме того, что нужно:) cfg видимо какой то глобальный и Вы его постоянно модифицируете.

Comment: Ну так может происходит переаллокация вектора? Функций перемещения в вашем классе `frame` нет, т.е. переаллокация делается через копирование и деструкцию. Именно эту деструкцию вы и видите. Чему равно `capacity()` вектора перед добавлением второго элемента?

Comment: @Iceman, в ответе на предыдущий вопрос про деструктор же написано, что нужно свой конструктор перемещения задать...